# Set selected items in asp.core razor pages

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core, html-select

I'm using ASP Core Razor pages.
This my Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
    [BindProperty]
        public List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> CCusers { get; set; }

and here I fill CCusers with data:
 CCusers =new List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>() {
                 new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "HR", Selected = true },
                 new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "IT", Selected = false },
                 new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Account", Selected = false },

            };
```

In Razor Page,    I used two different select:

```
    <select asp-for="CCusers" asp-items="@Model.CCusers" id="CCusers" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker"> </select>

//and this:

    @Html.DropDownList("NewSelect", Model.CCusers, new { @class = "selectpicker", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

and this the result of both of them:

```
<select id="CCusers" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker" name="CCusers"> 
<option value="1">HR</option>
<option value="2">IT</option>
<option value="3">Account</option>
</select>          

<select class="selectpicker" id="NewSelect" multiple="multiple" name="NewSelect">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">HR</option>
    <option value="2">IT</option>
    <option value="3">Account</option>
    </select>
```

The Core Select didn't set the selected item while the @Httml.DropDownList did it.
What I'm missing in the first select?

Comment: You will probably need to use the `asp-for` attribute. See https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I already used it.

Comment: In the above it would be something like `asp-for="@Model.CCuserIds"` - see *Multiple Select* section in the above link for further details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper), you will need to set `asp-for` which specifies the model proprety name for the `select` element.

For your issue, you need to define new property for `selected CCusers` instead of binding the `CCusers` to `asp-for` directly.

You could refer code below:

Page

```cs
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int[] SelectedCCuserIds { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> CCusers { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
       SelectedCCuserIds = new int[] { 1, 2 };
       CCusers = new List<SelectListItem>() 
          {
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "HR" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "IT" },
            new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Account" },
          };
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            var result = SelectedCCuserIds;
            return RedirectToAction("OnGet");
        }
    }
```

View

```cs
@page
@model CoreRazor.Pages.EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
<form method="post">
  <select asp-for="@Model.SelectedCCuserIds" asp-items="@Model.CCusers" 
          multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker"> </select>    
          @*@Html.DropDownList("NewSelect", Model.CCusers, new { @class = "selectpicker", 
     @multiple = "multiple" })*@
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```