# How to change option element of the drop-down list in to selected according to the value in ViewData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `ViewData["Mother"]` and which contains data of Mother entity. I want to set the relevant `option` element of the `drop-down list` to `selected` according to the value in my `ViewData["Mother"]`.
As an example - if `ViewData["Mother"]` is `Buddhism`, the `option` element which contains `Buddhism` value should be set to `selected`.

Mother.cs

```cs
public class Mother
{
    [Key,Required,Display(Name = "NIC"),MaxLength(12)]
    public string NIC { get; set; }
    [Required,Display(Name = "Full Name"),MaxLength(100)]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(15)]  public string Religion { get; set; }
}
```

controller.cs

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
       var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).FirstOrDefault();
       ViewData["Mother"] = Mother;
    }
    else
    {
        var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == "5861V").FirstOrDefault();
        ViewData["Mother"] = Mother;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml;

```
@{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother; }
@section Scripts{<script> $(function () { $("select#ReligionM").val("@m.Religion");})</script>}
<label asp-for="ReligionM">Religion</label>
<select asp-for="ReligionM" name="ReligionM" >
    <option>Please select your Religion</option>
    <option value="Buddhism">Buddhism</option>
    <option value="Catholic">Catholic</option>                                                  
</select> 
...
```

Comment: I still don't get it. You mean: if `ViewData["Mother"]` is `Buddhism`, the option element which contains `Buddhism` value is selected. Is it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set selected items in asp.core razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229988/set-selected-items-in-asp-core-razor-pages)

Comment: Yes. That is what I need.

Comment: if ViewData["Mother"] is Buddhism, the option element which contains Buddhism value is selected. – This is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jquery` to get the value of ViewData["Mother"] and let select control to select that value by default.

Change your view like this :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

@{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother;  }
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("select#ReligionM option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val()== "@m.Religion") {
                    $("select#ReligionM").val("@m.Religion");
                }
            }) 
        })</script>
}
<label asp-for="FNameM">Name in full</label>
<input asp-for="FNameM" name="FNameM" type="text" value="@m.FName">

<label asp-for="ReligionM">Religion</label>
<select asp-for="ReligionM" name="ReligionM">
    <option>Please select your Religion</option>
    <option value="Buddhism">Buddhism</option>
    <option value="Catholic">Catholic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion looks right. But it does not work for me. I put your `js code` at the next line to the `var m` line. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: @chandrasiri, I'm not sure about your current wording? If you want to move to the next line, you need to move in `as a whole` instead of just moving the js line of code.You can provide us with your current code,and I have updated the writing style based on your comment, you can refer to it first.

Comment: @chandrasiri，after seeing your code, I know your issue. I need to confirm with you again, `ViewData["Mother"] returns an entity class`, then you just need the value of `m.FName` to match the value of option, right? If so, please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: @chandrasiri, yes, I have already seen it, please look at my updated answer and test again.

Comment: What I need is, if `ViewData["Mother"]` is `Buddhism`, the `option` element which contains `Buddhism` value should be set to `selected`

Comment: @chandrasiric, yes, i know this is your requirement. However, the `ViewData["Mother"] is an entity` which contains two fields `NIC`  and `FName` , it is not a string ,so you should tell me `which field` you want to get to match the option value?

Comment: Sorry it was a my mistake. I am so sorry. There is a `Religion` field. I will update my post

Comment: @chandrasiri, i have updated my answer based on your edit post, you can to refer it.